# Solving the Cauchy Euler equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Having the Laplace operator in polar coordinates

\begin{equation}
  \Delta=  F_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}F_r+\frac{1}{r^2}F_{\theta\theta}
\end{equation}

on $\mathscr{D}_u:0\leq r\leq 1$ and $0\leq \theta \leq \pi/2$

\begin{equation}
  \bigg(F_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}F_r+\frac{1}{r^2}F_{\theta\theta}\bigg)u(r,\theta)=0
\end{equation}

Separation of variables  $u(r,\theta)=R(r)\Theta(\theta)$ gives the two ODEs:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
  R_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}R_r-\frac{k^2}{r^2}R=0 \\
  \Theta_{\theta\theta}+k^2\Theta=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Solving the first:

\begin{equation}
    \begin{array}{cc}
      R_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}R_r-\frac{k^2}{r^2}R=0, \ set \ R=y(x)\\
      y''+\frac{1}{x}y'-\frac{k^2}{x^2}y=0, \ trial\ solution:\ y=x^r\\
      r(r-1)x^{r-2}+rx^{r-2}-k^2x^{r-2}=0\\
      r=\pm k
    \end{array}
\end{equation}

The solutions for the first ODE are:

\begin{equation}
R_1(r)=r^{\pm k} \wedge R_2(r)=r^{\pm k}\ln r    
\end{equation}

Since there are no complex root in the characteristic equation, I don't include these.

Is this correct?

Comment: The exponential solution $e^{mr}$ is only applicable to homogeneous equations with constant coefficients. Your equation is inhomogeneous ($k^2$ on RHS) and has non-constant coefficients ($1/r$). To solve this equation, you can multiply by $r$ and then note $\partial_r (r R_r)=$LHS

Comment: Thanks Sal. Does this mean that that variable term is changing the whole method of solution? So here we do integration steps twice?

Comment: If there are constant coefficients, you can use it to find the homogeneous solution. It doesn't matter if the inhomogeneous term is a constant or complicated function since you'll be setting RHS$=0$ for the homogeneous solution

Comment: Thanks, I will update it with a solution

Comment: The non constant coefficient $1/r$ does change the solution method entirely for the homogeneous equation. In this case we were able to simplify the LHS by inspection, but in the more general case one has to resort to power series solutions. Also, substituting a candidate solution into the equation is a good way to check if it actually is a solution

Comment: Do you mean to guess a trial function or expansion by series  are the two main methods?

Comment: Multiplication with $r^2$ turns this into an Euler-Cauchy equation. The trial basis solution for its homogeneous equation is $R(r)=r^m$, you get a characteristic equation $m^2=0$ which results in basis solutions $1$ and $\ln(r)$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Then the characteristic equation is still valid. Did I misunderstand Sal?

Comment: It is a characteristic equation for Euler-Cauchy DE, not for linear DE with constant coefficients. There exists a translation between the two cases, $r=e^s$, $u(s)=R(e^s)$ has constant coefficients in the DE for $u$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann can you check the update?

Comment: This is still wrong. $m$ is a constant parameter, $r$ is the independent variable. They do not go together. You may accidentally get something that looks correct, but then in the next equation that fails. // With the basis solutions for the homogeneous equation you can now apply the variation-of-parameters method to get a solution for the inhomogeneous equation.

Comment: No, this is absurd. A constant can not be a non-trivial function of the independent variable. Do not try to rescue this failed approach by making it more ridiculous.

Comment: Well, Not trying to rescue this is caused by there is no explicit solution given here. So please either give a solution or don't criticize.

Comment: I did, in my first comment. // Please take care to not change the question too much. If a change to the question removes the context for existing answers, it is better to ask a new question. With the last changes you are close to that point.

Comment: Thanks for that. I take that my only question at this point is whether the solution with the natural log should be with or without $r^{\pm k}$ added to it? I assume that since the final solution is a superposition of the $r_1$ and $r_2$ there is no need to add $r^{\pm k}$ to the $r^{\pm k}\ln r$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attempt to clarify the comments.

For any *linear* ordinary differential equation (ODE), the general solution may be written as the sum of a homogeneous $R_H$ plus particular $R_P$ solution

$$
R(r)=R_H(r)+R_P(r)
$$
The particular solution may be found by [variation of parameters](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/VariationofParameters.aspx) or [undetermined coefficients](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx). The method of obtaining $R_P$ *does not* depend on the type of the ODE. Of course, if the ODE is homogenous then we don't worry about $R_P$.

There is no general solution to arbitrary ODEs of order above one. For example

$$
f(r)R''(r)+g(r)R'(r)+h(r)R(r)=0
$$

Where $f$, $g$, and $h$ are known arbitrary functions, cannot be solved in generality, even though the solution exists. Only in some *special cases* can we obtain an exact closed form solution. Eg, when $f$ and $g$ and $h$ are *constants*, the solution may be found using the exponential ansatz $R(r)\stackrel{?}{=}e^{mr}$. Another *special case* is when  $f \propto r^2$, $g \propto r$ and $h =\text{const.}$, which is called a [Cauchy-Euler equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation), for which the solution may be found using the ansatz $R(r)\stackrel{?}{=}r^m$.

In the general case, the way to make progress is to:

1. Transform the equation into one of the special cases by transforming the dependent or independent variable or both.
2. Seek a power series solution (guaranteed under certain niceness conditions on $f$, $g$, $h$). There's an example on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series_solution_of_differential_equations).
3. Guess a solution and check.

**Update**

We should not confuse the method of finding $R_H$ and $R_P$. As an example, let us study your equation

$$\tag{1}
r^2R''+rR'=r^2k^2
$$

I have multiplied the whole equation by $r^2$ so that the *homogeneous equation* will be in the Cauchy-Euler form. Now we find $R_H$. The homogeneous equation is

$$\tag{2}
r^2R_H''+rR_H'=0
$$

Using the ansatz $R_H=r^m$ we have

$$
r^2m(m-1)r^{m-2}+rmr^{m-1}=0 \\
m^2=0
$$

Notice this would not have been progress if we had kept the inhomogeneous RHS. Looking at the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation), we see that for repeated $m$ values, the solution is

$$
R_H=c_1r^m \ln(r)+c_2 r^m
$$

Where in our case $m=0$ hence

$$
R_H=c_1 \ln(r)+c_2
$$

This matches what we would get directly if we had written (2) as

$$
r \frac{d}{dr}\left(r R_H' \right)=0
$$

Now we must find one particular solution $R_P$. The RHS is a polynomial so we guess a polynomial of the same degree (this is undetermined coefficients)

$$\tag{3}
R_P\stackrel{?}{=}\alpha+\beta r+\gamma r^2
$$

What remains is to substitute (3) into (1) and solve for $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$. If this can be done consistently then (3) is a particular solution and we are done. In this case, $\beta=0$, $\gamma=k^2/4$ and $\alpha$ is any number (it may be absorbed into $c_2$).

Comment: Thanks Sal, do you have a reference to an example of how to seek a power solution , as in point 2?

Comment: can you check the update?