# Solving the Laplace equation in polar coodinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, harmonic-functions

So, I have the Laplace equation to solve in polar coordinates. I have the following details:

\begin{equation}
\Delta u=0
\end{equation}

with boundary conditions

\begin{cases}
u(r,0)=u(r,\pi/2)=0\\
u(1,\theta)=-\frac{2\theta}{\pi}\\
\end{cases}
and $r, \theta$ are in the domain $\Omega := (0, 1) \times \Big(0, \frac\pi 2 \Big)$.

We start by setting up the equation in differentials.
Make a seperation of variables Ansatz $u = R\Theta, R=R(r) \neq R(\theta), \Theta = \Theta(\theta) \neq \Theta(r)$ and use the definition of the Laplacian in polar coordinates in the plane:

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\right)R\Theta=0
\end{equation}

We rearrange

\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)R\Theta+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}R\Theta&=0 \\
\Theta\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)R+R\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\Theta&=0
\end{align}

and multiply by $r^2$
$$
\Theta\left(r^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}+r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)R+R\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\Theta=0
$$
divide by $R \Theta$
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{r^2\frac{\partial^2R}{\partial r^2}+r\frac{\partial R}{\partial r}}{R}\right) + \frac{\frac{\partial^2\Theta}{\partial\theta^2}}{\Theta}= 0.
\end{equation}
Since this has to hold $\forall \: r, \theta$, but $R, \Theta$ are independent of the "other" coordinate, both summands have to be constant:
$$
\left(\frac{r^2\frac{\partial^2R}{\partial r^2}+r\frac{\partial R}{\partial r}}{R}\right)=-\frac{\frac{\partial^2\Theta}{\partial\theta^2}}{\Theta}=k^2
$$

This gives two ODEs:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
fr^2R''+rR'-k^2R=0 \\
\Theta''+k^2\Theta=0
\end{array}
\end{equation}

We solve the first:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
fr^2R''+rR'-k^2R=0 \\
R''+\frac{1}{r}R'-\frac{k^2}{r^2}R=0 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

We follow [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4414420/solving-the-cauchy-euler-equation?noredirect=1#comment9237609_4414420) earlier post of mine to solve this Euler-Laplace equation and obtain it solutions:

\begin{equation}
R_1(r)=r^{\pm k} \wedge R_2(r)=r^{\pm k}\ln r    
\end{equation}

For the second, we solve it using the characteristic determinant

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
f\Theta''+k^2\Theta=0\\
m=\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-4k^2}\rightarrow m=\pm ik
\end{array}
\end{equation}

This gives the solution to the second ODE:

$$
f\Theta(\theta)=Ae^{ik}+Be^{-ik}
$$
To comply with the boundary condition $u(r, 0) = u (r, \pi/2) = 0$ there are no cosine terms, thus:
$$
\Theta(\theta)=A \sin(ik\theta)
$$

Since $u=R\Theta$ we combine the two and get:

\begin{equation}
u(r,\theta)=(r^{\pm k} +r^{\pm k}\ln r )A \sin(ik\theta)
\end{equation}

Using boundary condition $u(r, 0) = u (r, \pi/2) = 0$ I get, disregarding for the radial part of the function (can one do that?)

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
aA \sin(ik\pi/2)=0\\
ik\pi/2=n\pi \\
k=\frac{2n}{i}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Proceeding to the second B.C. $u(1,\theta)=-\frac{2\theta}{\pi}$

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
aA\sin(2n\theta)\big(r^{2n/i}+r^{2n/i}\ln r\big)=-\frac{2\theta}{\pi}\\
A=-\frac{2 r^{2 i n}\theta \csc(2 n \theta)}{\pi}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

This gives the final solution:

\begin{equation}
u(r,\theta)=-\frac{2}{\pi}\big(r^{2 i n}\theta \sin(2n\theta)\csc(2 n \theta)\big)(r^{\pm \frac{2n}{i}} +r^{\pm \frac{2n}{i}}\ln r    )
\end{equation}

and it looks like this:

[image]

But this solution does not agree with the examinators' solution:

$u(r,\theta)=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k}r^{2k}\sin(2k\theta)$

Is there an error here, that the readers can see?

Thanks

Comment: Why it looks not correct?

Comment: Because the exams correct solution is $u(r,\theta)=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k}r^{2k}\sin(2k\theta)$

Comment: First, because you have used $k^{2}$ for the separation constant _and_ $k$ for the summation variable in the examiners solution, to avoid confusion let the separation constant be $\lambda^{2}$ instead. There shouldn't be an imaginary unit in the argument of $\sin$ in the $\Theta$ solution; this would make your solution $\sinh$. Clearly, $\Theta = A \cos(\lambda \theta) + B \sin(\lambda \theta)$. Then $u(r, 0) = 0 \implies A = 0$. Finally, $$u(r, \pi/2) = 0 \implies B \sin (\lambda \pi /2) = 0 \implies \lambda \pi/2 = n \pi, \ \ \ \forall n \ge 1 \implies \lambda = 2n, \ \ \ \forall n \ge 1$$

Comment: @Mattos, thanks I removed the imaginary unit , as you say, as it disappears when $k=2n/i$. I will consider your use of lambda in the future.  So in total, this solution is acceptable? Still I can't see what is B in your result.

Comment: Your solution is still wrong; you have the eigenvalue $k$ (i.e $\lambda$) is complex $\lambda=2n/i$ when it is not. And $B$ is just a constant and arbitrary at this point, you can't determine its value until you apply the final boundary conditions.

Comment: The solutions to the ODEs are \begin{align}\lambda&=2n\\\Theta&=B_{n}\sin(2n\theta)\\R&=C_{n}r^{2n}+D_{n} r^{-2n}\end{align} for $n=1,2,\dots$, where the coefficients are to be determined by the boundary condition $u(1,\theta)$. Assuming you want $u<\infty$ at $r=0$, then $D_{n}=0$ and the solution is a superposition $$u(r,\theta)=\sum_{n\ge 1}B_{n}\sin(2n\theta)C_{n}r^{2n}=\sum_{n \ge 1}\tilde{B}_{n}\sin(2n\theta)r^{2n}$$ Now apply the boundary condition to find $\tilde{B}_{n}$ using the [orthogonality relations](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially bundling @mattos comments into an answer, we have to solve the two ODEs carefully.

Let's consider the ODE for $R$ first. As observed, it is the classic second order Cauchy-Euler equation. Following the [procedure outlined in the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation#Second_order_%E2%80%93_solving_through_trial_solution), you find that for the Ansatz $R(r) = r^m$ you get the indicial equation
$$m^2 -k^2 = 0$$ with the obvious roots $m = \pm k$.
In this case, the solution is $$R(r) = c_1 r^{-k} + c_2 r^k.$$
Although it is not directly mentioned in the task, you probably want a bounded solution, especially for $r \to 0$, thus you set $c_1 = 0$. This assumes that $k>0$, the case $k <0$ is symmetric (then, $c_2 = 0$). See below why the distinction into $k < 0$ or $k>0$ is valid in general and does not lead to loss of generality.

Now the second ODE: By inspection / knowledge of the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian / properties of $\sin, \cos$ it is immediately clear that
$$\Theta '' = -k^2\theta$$
is solved by the Ansatz
$$\Theta(\theta) = c_3 \sin(k\theta) + c_4 \cos(k \theta).$$
As you already mentioned, the cosine drops out because of the boundary condition $u(r, 0) \overset{!}{=} 0$ i.e., $c_4 = 0$.
The second boundary condition in $\theta$, $u(r, \pi/2) \overset{!}{=} 0$ gives not directly a restriction for $c_3$, but instead for the yet unspecified constant $k$. For $\sin(k \pi/2) = 0$ to be fulfilled, you need that $k = 2 \cdot i , i \in \mathbb Z$ ($i$ is here not the complex unit).
This brings us basically to the last comment by @mattos:

\begin{align} 
k &= 2 i\\
R(r) &=c_2 r^{2i} \\
\Theta(\theta) &= c_3 \sin(2i\theta)
\end{align}
Because of the product form $u(r, \theta) = R(r) \Theta(\theta)$ you can bundle the remaining constants $c_2, c_3$ into one:
$$u(r, \theta) = \underbrace{\tilde c_i}_{=c_2 \cdot c_3} r^{2i} \sin(2i\theta). $$

The general solution is then a linear (the Laplace equation is linear) combination of the above:
$$
u(r, \theta) =  \sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} \tilde c_i r^{2i} \sin(2i\theta).
$$
Since $\sin(-x) = -\sin(x)$ we can restrict ourselves to $i \in \mathbb N_0$ and define $$c_i := \tilde c_i - \tilde c_{-i}.$$ This is equivalent to the previous mentioned distinction for $k>0$ (our choice) or the symmetric case with $k < 0$.
Furthermore, we should rule out $i=0$ since this corresponds to the trivial solution which also cannot satisfy the boundary condition
$$u(1, \theta) \overset{!}{=} -\frac{2\theta}{\pi}.$$

Thus we have
$$
u(r, \theta) =  \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} c_i r^{2i} \sin(2i\theta).
$$

Now it gets a slightly more involved again. The boundary condition $u(1, \theta) \overset{!}{=} -\frac{2\theta}{\pi}$ determines the unknown coefficients $c_i$ through
$$
u(r=1, \theta) =  \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} c_i  \sin(2i\theta).
$$
Now comes the trick: Since the $\sin(2i \theta)$ are orthogonal, it holds that
$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(2i\theta) \sin(2j\theta) \mathrm d \theta = \frac{\pi}{4} \delta_{ij}$$ with $\delta_{ij}$ being the [Kronecker delta.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)
This is extremely helpful:
To get the $c_i$'th coefficient, you multiply
$$u(r=1, \theta) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} c_i  \sin(2i\theta) = -\frac{2\theta}{\pi} $$
with $\sin(2i\theta)$ and integrate $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi/2$ which "singles out" $c_i \cdot \frac{\pi}{4} $ on the LHS:
\begin{align}
c_i \cdot \frac{\pi}{4} &= \int_0^{\pi/2} -\frac{2\theta}{\pi} \sin(2i\theta) \mathrm d \theta  \\
\Leftrightarrow c_i&= - \frac{8}{\pi^2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \theta \sin(2i\theta) \mathrm d \theta \\
\Leftrightarrow c_i&= - \frac{8}{\pi^2} \Bigg[ \frac{\sin(2i\theta) - 2i \theta \cos(2i\theta) }{(2i)^2} \Bigg]_0^{\pi/2} \\
\Leftrightarrow c_i&= - \frac{2}{(i\pi)^2 } \bigg( 0 - 2i \pi/2 (-1)^i - \Big( 0 - 0 \cdot 1) \bigg) \\
\Leftrightarrow c_i&= \frac{2(-1)^i}{i \pi}
\end{align}

and thus finally
$$
u(r, \theta) = \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^i}{i} r^{2i} \sin(2i\theta).
$$

Comment: Thanks for this solution Dan.